# Get sum of price multiplied by quantity over nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, sum

I have an array of object and within object there are arrays like this

```
[ 
     {
       orderId: 123, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020', 
       products: [ {product: 'choco', price: 300, qty: 3}, {product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2} ] 
     },
     {
       orderId: 124, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020', 
       products: [ {product: 'butter', price: 100, qty: 1}, {product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2} ] 
     } 
]
```

and I want to sum all the price and quantity of the products(The result should be 2400). Is there a way to do it? Iam using React js and firestore as database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use map, reduce, and flat function as shown below:

```js
const data = [ 
     {
       orderId: 123, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020', 
       products: [ {product: 'choco', price: 300, qty: 3}, {product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2} ] 
     },
     {
       orderId: 124, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020', 
       products: [ {product: 'butter', price: 100, qty: 1}, {product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2} ] 
     } 
]

const pricesArray = data.map(item=>item.products.map(product=>product.price*product.qty));
console.log(pricesArray.flat().reduce((acc,sum)=>acc+sum));
```

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{orderId: 123, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020',products: [{ product: 'choco', price: 300, qty: 3 }, { product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2 }]},{orderId: 124, orderStatus: 'Pending', date: 'june 13, 2020',products: [{ product: 'butter', price: 100, qty: 1 }, { product: 'milk', price: 350, qty: 2 }]}]

let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].products.length; j++) {
        sum += data[i].products[j].price * data[i].products[j].qty
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```